# Recent Timezone changes in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it just me or has something in Google changed recently? I have a function that adds a timestamp to edits that was working just fine, and just the other day it broke.

It broke in the sense that it used to stamp the time in my timezone - as is specified by the function formatting I use, Now it appears to be timestamping in GMT instead of GMT-8. Nothing has changed in my script, so what happened?

```
function happyFunTime() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var columnNum = r.getColumn();
  var timeLastCalledColumnOffset = getTimeLastCalledColumnOffset();
  var rowNum = r.getRow();

if (rowNum <=1) return;

  timeLastCalledColumnOffset++;
  // set dateCell = the current row at column J
  var dateCell = s.getRange(rowNum, timeLastCalledColumnOffset);


  var tZone= "GMT-8";
  // Format the current date into datetime format 
  var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tZone, "MMM-dd-yyyy h:mm a");

  // Set the cell value.  Add apostrophe to force text treatment & keep the spreadsheet from reformatting
    dateCell.setValue("'" + dateTime);

}
```

`getTimeLastCalledColumnOffset()` is a custom function to return a number of the column that contains the value I'm interested in (J, so 9 in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are a issue from yesterday because this string "GMT-2" or "GMT-0200" has been working fine and now is faulty.

You can change this line :

```
   var tZone= "GMT-8"
```

to this one

```
   var tZone= "GMT-08:00"
```

or you can get the time zone with this lines of code :

```
  var FUS1 = new Date().toString().substr(25,8);  // I use FUS1 instead of tZone

  // GMT-0800  ->  GMT-08:00 , ...
  var FUS1 = FUS1.substr(0,6) + ':' + FUS1.substr(6)

  // Format the current date into datetime format 
  var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1 , "MMM-dd-yyyy h:mm a");
```

or you can writte your time zone from here :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

"America/Dawson" -> -08:00 (I don't know where you live :-( )

and this code :

```
  var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Dawson" , "MMM-dd-yyyy h:mm a");
```

Note: if you want to format a date captured from a DateBox (label, textbox, ...) then, the last line, can be something like:

```
   var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(e.paramameter.datebox), "America/Dawson" , "MMM-dd-yyyy h:mm
```

Sergi

Comment: Or more simply for FUS1 : `var FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";`

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you!  Will this handle daylight savings time properly or do I need to look into that?

Comment: It will but if you work with events that are in summer while you are not, then you should use `new Date(the time of the event).toString...` instead of a simple `new Date()` (and of course also for the inverse case)

Comment: Hello Serge, I added some of your comments to the code. About your first comment (+ ': 00'): please note that there are some time zones with ': 30' at the end, eg 'Asia / Calcutta'.

Answer (score 1):

Another easy solution to get the right string to include in `Utilities.formatDate()` is to use  `Session.getTimeZone()` which returns for example `'Europe/Paris'` in my case and is a valid argument.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, that is good information.  I suspect this will not be useful in my case, as I have collaborators in other timezones.  Presumably this will return the timezone of the user that is running the script?  I need to be able to specify a specific timezone - for now that timezone happens to coincide with my own, I'm not sure if that will ever change but that's the situation as of today.

Answer (score 0):

> We can directly change the time zone of spreadsheet using below line

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().setSpreadsheetTimeZone(Session.getScriptTimeZone())`